# Trying to focus on an element in a $mdSideNav

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am making an angular app that has a chat function. I have a sidenav that loads messages and a chat box. The chat box is fixed to the bottom of the screen and the messages are separately scrollable above it. I would like to focus on the last message when the sidenav is opened. I am no sure how to do this however as the messages are being displayed in an ng-repeat.

HTML:

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-flow: column; height: 100%;">
<div>
    <md-toolbar class="md-blue-grey" >
        <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <span>Chat</span>
        </h1>
    </md-toolbar>
</div>
<div style="min-height: 0; flex: 1; overflow: auto;">
    <div style="height: 200px;">
        <div id="messages" ng-repeat="mess in messages track by $index" >

    <md-card  ng-attr-id="mess{{$index}}"  >

        <p ><b>{{mess.user}}</b></p>
        <p >{{mess.time | date:'medium'}}</p>
    </md-card>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <chat-input></chat-input>
</div>
</div>
```

I dont think you guys need to see my Javascript but if you do. Let me know and I will post it. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This will change the background-color of yr message, similarly u can add yr custom effects to last message.

```
<md-card  ng-attr-id="mess{{$index}}"  >
   <span ng-style="$last && {'background-color':'red'}">
      <p ><b>{{mess.user}}</b></p>
      <p >{{mess.time | date:'medium'}}</p>
   </span>
</md-card>
```

Comment: This will highlight the last md-card in yr md-cards.                                  Make a plunk  with yr code for quick help.